# Unable to connect to Akka HTTP running on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, akka-http

I'm moving an Akka HTTP application to AWS and am stumped at this problem. The Akka HTTP server is booted like so:

```scala
Http().bindAndHandle(routes, "0.0.0.0", 5377)
```

The EC2 Instance is started with the aws CLI:

```bash
aws ec2 run-instances \
  --count 1 \
  --instance-type t2.micro \
  --key-name variant-us-west-1 \
  --region $region \
  --subnet-id subnet-bc22ebda \
  --security-group-ids sg-0901a32ad173d6aae \
  --image-id ami-0911f75c0510b955d  `#ubuntu-openjdk-17-jre-headless` \
  --output text --query 'Instances[*].InstanceId'
```

The AMI in question is a private one of mine that has nothing but Java and AWS CLI. The security group `sg-0901a32ad173d6aae` opens the port in question 5377 for inbound traffic:
[image]

The running instance does show these same rules in the Security tab:
[image]

However, when I try to curl it from my local system outside of AWS, I get an error:

```bash
curl http://3.101.78.138:5377 
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 3.101.78.138 port 5377 after 19 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I think that the request gets to the server because `curl` fails fast. If I change to a port that is not open, it takes much longer to time out. So I am suspecting my Akka HTTP configuration, but can't think of anything.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you packing your app? a jar? a war? maybe with [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager)? did the application start ok? any error message during the start up? are you able to connect to the machine and execute curl to an endpoint? please add more debugging such as how you build the app, log messages and else

Comment: Yeah, with the native packager. The app works fine. If I ssh on the EC2 instance, I can do `curl http://localhost:5377` no problem.

Comment: have you exposed that port in the container? Could you show how you setup the build of the docker image?

Comment: That's a good guess, but I am not running in Docker. Eventually, but for now directly on the JVM.

Comment: Is port 5377 open to all? run `netstat -tlpan` you should see something like: `tcp        0    0 0.0.0.0:5377    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    <pid>/java`

Comment: Thank you, @TsalTroser. This got me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Tsal Troser's comment got me on the right track. Turns out, Java 17 was binding an IP6 address, even though the interface I am passing to Akka "0.0.0.0" is an IP4 interface. I don't quite understand the network details here, but passing `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to the runtime solved my problem. Thank you, Gastón Schabas for your comments as well.